# A program that generates Java project from UML

Tags: java, uml, code-generation

Do you know any program that generates the whole Java project from UML for you with the classes, attributes, packages, function you have defined?

The program should be free.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ooow! so you wanna a holy bread-baker without spending any effort, huh? this is a bad question, sorry.

Comment: I can google, but I don't want to test 10 Uml programs to find the best. So its easier to ask some people who have some experience and know which programm is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually more common than generally thought of. I've seen Enterprise Architect and MagicDrawn been used mostly. They even let you run a simulation and fill in methods with actualy code in state charts for example.

Comment: Enterprise Architect looks fine, but theres only a 30 day trial version. Do you know any other programm which is similar in the functionality of Enterprise Architect, but is for free?

Comment: Actually I do know that there are none that work good enough. Only one that tries to step on the same territory is ArgoUML.

Comment: Year i tried this for several minutes ... but i don't like ArgoUML.